# error in Map functions in react functions

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-redux

I'm new to react js and i am stuck with this.Please send help..

```
  const rows = results.map((data, i) => {
    const district=data.districtData;
    const state=data.state;
    return (
      
        <tr
          key={i}
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target={`#${data.state}`}
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <td>{data.state}</td>
          <td>{data.confirmed}</td>
          <td>{data.active}</td>
          <td>{data.recovered}</td>
          <td>{data.deaths}</td>
        </tr>
        district.map((data, i) => {
          return (
            <tr className=" collapse" id={state} key={data.id}>
              <td>{data.id}</td>
              <td>{data.active}</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
              <td>fad</td>
            </tr>
          );
        }); 
    );
  });
```

This is my code snippet .I am using [https://api.covidindiatracker.com/state_data.json][1] API for my project
I need a table that displays the state details and when the row is clicked the district details should be displayed.I tried to used bootstrap collapse for this..

```
 const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://api.covidindiatracker.com/state_data.json")

      .then((res) => {
        setResults(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

The data from the API is stored in results using the hooks.
There is some error  in the rows function(syntactical error i guess)  Please help me find it and suggest corrections!
[1]: https://api.covidindiatracker.com/state_data.json

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Change this `setResults(res.data);` to `setResults(res);`

Comment: ./src/pages/india.js
  Line 42:9:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  40 |           <td>{data.deaths}</td>
  41 |         </tr>
> 42 |         district.map((data, i) => {
     |         ^
  43 |           return (
  44 |             <tr className=" collapse" id={state} key={data.id}>
  45 |               <td>{data.id}</td>

Comment: You should not use the same iterator name. 
Please check line 1 of your function expression "const rows = results.map((data, i) => {", here "data" is the iterator and later on "district.map((data, i) => {" you're using the same "iterator" name which I guess is creating issue. 
please let me know, if that's the issue.

Comment: the error you posted is syntax error.

Comment: yeah i tried what u said..Doesnt seem to work @fahadtufail

Comment: okay whats line number  Line 42:9 in your component

Comment: <tr className=" collapse" id={state} key={data.id}> @fahadtufail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose javascript code `district.map` with `{}` in your JSX.

```
const rows = results.map((data, i) => {
    const district = data.districtData;
    const state = data.state;
    return (
      <>
        <tr
          key={i}
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target={`#${data.state}`}
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <td>{data.state}</td>
          <td>{data.confirmed}</td>
          <td>{data.active}</td>
          <td>{data.recovered}</td>
          <td>{data.deaths}</td>
        </tr>


        {
          district.map((value, i) => (
            <tr className=" collapse" id={state} key={data.id}>
              <td>{data.id}</td>
              <td>{data.active}</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
              <td>fad</td>
            </tr>
          )
          )
        }


      </>
    );

  });
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: same error,shall i send my send code so that u can find the error?

Comment: It will be easier that way to debug.

Comment: Here is the github link!Thank you in advance

Comment: Cheers @sowmicaML, just on the side note, you are getting a lot of warning in console regarding same `key`. You might want to make unique `key` maybe using `index` with `id` or `value` otherwise there might be a performance hit.